# Счетчик который добавляет значение раз в сутки

Tags: php, wordpress

Как реализовать счетчик который добавляет значение раз в сутки на WordPress?

Comment: А причем тут `wordpress`?

Comment: Советую объяснить подробней, что именно Вам требуется. Так Вы увеличите шансы получить дельный совет.

Answer (score 0):

В файл темы function.php надо добавить такой код:

```
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'my_task_hook' ) ) {
wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'my_task_hook' );
```

}

```
function my_task_function() {
    $counter = get_option('my_counter', 0);
    $counter++;
    update_option('my_counter', $counter);
    // использовать $counter
}
add_action( 'my_task_hook', 'my_task_function' );
```

и использовать переменную $counter там, где комментарий, либо считывать ее в нужном месте кода с помощью get_option, как в примере.